# How should a glide project import another project with a vendor/ directory?

Tags: go

The golang Glide packager automatically will install dependencies for a project, however, in doing so it pulls in dependencies from the vendor/, since many projects check in vendor dependencies.

How should one import a glide dependency which includes a vendor/ directory?

As of now, it appears that you can get errors such as :

`./scheduler.go:36: cannot use "github.com/jayunit100/my-project/vendor/github.com/spf13/pflag".CommandLine (type *"github.com/jayunit100/my-project/vendor/a/b/spf13/pflag".FlagSet)` 
as type 
`*"github.com/jayunit100/my-project/vendor/a/b/vendor/github.com/spf13/pflag".FlagSet`

- import as normal, and then manually delete `vendor/` so there are no redundancies.
- import as normal, and use some kind of configuration trick to avoid the `vendor/` dependency duplication?

Comment: but you should not have `vendor/` within `vendor/` folders.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is quite a common issue for people using glide. My team ran into the same issue and had to investigate for a while but eventually found that using the flatten operation solved this for us.

To do this pass the `-v` flag to your glide operations.

e.g. `glide up -v`

You can read more about it on the [glide docs](https://glide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/#updating-dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

My current solution has been to manually delete vendor/ directories from libraries which are brought in that keep vendor/.

... (Update) glide supports a --strip-vendor option.